# How to use CheckedProvider-Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guice for Dependency injection. I want to use @CheckedProvides as object construction may throw exception and I do not want it to be wrapped up in ProvisionException. I found this useful but I am not able to get the complete picture. I have created an interface which is extending CheckedProvider interface. Now I want to know what the implementing class of this interface will contain?

My interface looks like

```
public interface TokenEncrypterProvider <T> extends CheckedProvider<T> {
    T get() throws  ExceptionInInitializerError;
}
```

i want it to be used as

```
@Provides
public TokenManager getTokenManager(SomeClass obj) {
    return new TokenManager(obj);
}

@CheckedProvides(TokenEncrypterProvider.class)
    public SomeClass getEncrypter() {
        try {
            return new SomeClassFactory()
                    .buildEncryptionClient(AppConfig.findString("xyz"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

public class TokenManager {
private final SomeClass obj;
    @Inject
    public TokenManager(SomeClass obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
...
}
```

now for binding what should I write

```
bind(TokenEncrypterProvider.class).toProvider(WHICHCLASS?.class);
```

or if it is not the way to use CheckedProvides, please suggest a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Guice 3+ or 4+. You don't have to bind your provider if you are using `CheckedProvides` annotations.

You have to add `install(ThrowingProviderBinder.forModule(this))` in the `configure()` method of your module to be able to use `@CheckedProvides` methods.

[Documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders#using-checkedprovides-new-in-guice-30)